# Exclude subfolders of a website in Stylish?

Tags: css, regex, stylish

Is there a way to exclude subfolders of a website using Stylish?

```
@-moz-document domain("www.website.com") { }
```

Will affect all pages of website.com. The problem is, this website also hosts a wiki (`www.website.com/wiki/*`), which has an entirely different style.
Some of the Stylish CSS affects this wiki as well, which I want to avoid.

Is there any way to do this? I've read: [Disable stylish on certain sites in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/463153/disable-stylish-on-certain-sites-in-firefox), but this is for a global style, which I don't have.

I should say I don't understand anything of regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about coding in Stylish, but assuming you can use RegEx, you could try the following:

```
www.website.com(?!\/wiki\/).*
```

So your full code will be:

```
@-moz-document regexp('https?://www\\.website\\.com(?!/wiki/).*') {
  ...
}
```

Here is how the RegEx works:

```
http          # Selects HTTP protocol
s?            # Options s for HTTPS protocol
://           # :// After Protocol
www           # www
\\.           # Escaped . (dot)
website\\.com # Website
(?!           # Start of negative lookahead, If anything inside is found, the match will fail
    /wiki/        # Don't match if inside /wiki/ directory
)             # End of negative lookahead
.*            # Selects any character (.) any amount of times (*)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d219)</kbd>

Comment: The answer needed some tweaking to work with Stylish. See https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/stylish/wiki/Applying-styles-to-specific-sites

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot!